# Execution of target "convert-conf" failed for the following reason - No valid xmlConfFile specified.

Tags: propel

After following the tutorial on the propel website and executing the following 2 command without error:

```
./propel-gen om
./propel-gen sql
```

I tried:

```
./propel-gen convert-conf
```

The following error occurs.

```
django@ubuntu{~/www/propel/addons/schema} (propel *+)$ ./propel-gen convert-conf
Buildfile: /home/django/www/propel/addons/schema/Propel/generator/build.xml

propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:
propel-project-builder > check-project-set:
propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:
propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:
propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:
propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:
propel-project-builder > configure:
     [echo] Loading project-specific props from /home/django/www/propel/addons/schema/build.properties
 [property] Loading /home/django/www/propel/addons/schema/build.properties

propel-project-builder > convert-conf:

    [phing] Calling Buildfile '/home/django/www/propel/addons/schema/Propel/generator/build-propel.xml' with target 'convert-conf'
 [property] Loading /media/SuperFast/www/propel/addons/schema/Propel/generator/./default.properties

propel > convert-conf:

     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] | Converting runtime config file to an     |
     [echo] | array dump for improved performance.     |
     [echo] |                                          |
     [echo] +------------------------------------------+
**Execution of target "convert-conf" failed for the following reason: /home/django/www/propel/addons/schema/Propel/generator/build-propel.xml:569:20: No valid xmlConfFile specified.
    [phing] /home/django/www/propel/addons/schema/Propel/generator/build-propel.xml:569:20: No valid xmlConfFile specified.**

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.2250 seconds
```

This is my build.properties: http://pastebin.com/seeE7d65
And here more outputs of my different tries:

http://pastebin.com/6Np5QYTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename your file `runtime.conf.xml` to `runtime-conf.xml` which is the expected filename ;)